# How to ensure that DAG is not recomputed after the driver is restarted?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, high-availability

How can I ensure that an entire DAG of spark is highly available i.e. not recomputed from scratch when the driver is restarted (default HA in yarn cluster mode).

Currently, I use spark to orchestrate multiple smaller jobs i.e.

- read table1
- hash some columns
- write to HDFS

this is performed for multiple tables.
Now when the driver is restarted i.e. when working on the second table the first one is reprocessed - though it already would have been stored successfully.

I believe that the default mechanism of checkpointing (the raw input values) would not make sense.
What would be a good solution here?
Is it possible to checkpoint the (small) configuration information and only reprocess what has not already been computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Spark is not a task orchestration tool. While it has built-in scheduler and some fault tolerance mechanisms built-in, it as suitable for granular task management, as for example server orchestration (hey, we can call `pipe` on each machine to execute bash scripts, right).

If you want granular recovery choose a minimal unit of computation that makes sense for a given process (read, hash, write looks like a good choice, based on the description), make it an application and use external orchestration to submit the jobs.

You can build poor man's alternative, by checking if expected output exist and skipping part of the job in that case, but really don't - we have variety of battle tested tools which can do way better job than this.

As a side note Spark doesn't provide HA for the driver, only supervision with automatic restarts. Also independent jobs (read -> transform -> write) create independent DAGs - there is no global DAG and proper checkpoint of the application would require full snapshot of its state (like good old [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/CLaSS/research/BLCR/)).

Answer (score 0):

> when the driver is restarted (default HA in yarn cluster mode).

When the driver of a Spark application is gone, your Spark application is gone and so are all the cached datasets. That's by default.

You have to use some sort of caching solution like https://www.alluxio.org/ or https://ignite.apache.org/. Both work with Spark and both claim to be offering the feature to outlive a Spark application.

There has been times when people used Spark Job Server to share data across Spark applications (which is similar to restarting Spark drivers).